# Google Maps not shown in the release mode

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

My question is common, but I have tried all the suggestions listed before to solve the issue of that Google Maps only shown in debug mode not in release mode.
The below have been tried (for sure I have used the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint for debug keystore and release keystore as per google documents):

1. Added different api Keys in the google_map_api.xml for debug and
   release.
2. Added same key for both debug and release modes.
3. Write the key manually in thee Manifest.xml
4. Refer to the string in the   Manifest.xml

Update:

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
      The API key for Google Maps-based APIs.
 -->
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="local.application.user.myApp.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: show your manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all suggested solutions (Thx for everyone). I tried to disable the Google Maps Api and re-enabled it again (from console.developers.google.co) and it has been working fine since then.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Google api console where select the app and in left side :
Release management=> App Signing=> copy **SHA-1 certificate** inside **App signing certificate**module and paste into the Google cloud console and add this SHA1 with your project and save it . it will work . it works me.

Comment: I will try your solution, but I believe the issue is not related to the signing in the Google Console, as I have tried to run the release version directly in my real phone with the same result.